# Creating and Using New `filter` with $filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Reading [Mastering Web Development with AngularJS](http://www.packtpub.com/angularjs-web-application-development/book), I'm trying to create and use a new filter that uses the `$filter` module/keyword.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl"> 
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in backlog | trim:4">
                <td>{{item}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
.filter("trim", function($filter) {
    var limitToFilter = $filter("limitTo");

    return function(input, limit) {
        console.log("input:", input, "limit:", limit);
        if(input.length > limit) {
            return limitToFilter(input, limit-3) + "...";
        }
        return input;
    };
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.backlog = ["asdfasdf", "BBBBBBBBB", "CCCCCCC", 
                     "DDDDDDD", "EEEE"];
}
```

I would've expected the first character (`4-3 = 1`) of each `$scope.backlog` item to show up. But it appears to print out the first characters of the first item in `$scope.backlog`, which doesn't make sense to me.

http://jsfiddle.net/9Q6Sk/

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get your code to work, but not using the built in `limitTo` filter. It might be a bug with the 1.2.1 version of angular, but I can get it to work in their example.  I'm going to investigate further.

The first change I made to your code is to move the filter from the `ng-repeat` to the actual item. Based on your description you want the first character of each `backlog` item, not the first backlog item.

**HTML**

```
    <tr ng-repeat="item in backlog">                
        <td>{{ item | trim:4 }}</td>            
    </tr>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module("myApp", []).filter("trim", function($filter) {

    return function(input, limit) {
    if(input.length > limit) {
        return $filter('limitTo')(input, limit-3);
    }
        return input;
    };
});
```

I'm going to continue to investigate why `limitTo` won't work, even when just applied by itself.

**UPDATE**

I found the reason that `limitTo` wasn't working.  You had Angular 1.0.1 as an external dependency which overruled the 1.2.1.  1.0.1 does not include the `limitTo` filter.
Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nuclearghost/bp4Mq/) for a working example

Comment: Hi @NuclearGhost, thanks. How did I have an Angular `1.0.1` dependency? I don't understand.

Comment: It was in the external dependencies of your jsfiddle. If you forked another fiddle it's possible it was from there. Remove it to get the limit to filter

Comment: @KevinMeredith have you resolved your issue?  Let us know if there are further problems, or please accept a working solution

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to notice is that you want to limit each **item** in the `backlog` so you shouldn't use the filter on the `ngRepeat` directive. The Second thing to note is when looking  at the syntax of your `limitToFilter` function this is what you'll see:

```
function (array, limit) {
    if (!(array instanceof Array)) return array;
    limit = int(limit);
    var out = [],
      i, n;

    // check that array is iterable
    if (!array || !(array instanceof Array))
      return out;

    // if abs(limit) exceeds maximum length, trim it
    if (limit > array.length)
      limit = array.length;
    else if (limit < -array.length)
      limit = -array.length;

    if (limit > 0) {
      i = 0;
      n = limit;
    } else {
      i = array.length + limit;
      n = array.length;
    }

    for (; i<n; i++) {
      out.push(array[i]);
    }

    return out;
  }
```

As you can clearly see, the function is operating on the **Array** type, not the **string** type. so in a nutshell you'll have to write your own filtering mechanism to limit the strings you want.

**UPDATE**

Actually I tried and got it working with the `ngRepeat` and all those stuff:
check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Q6Sk/2/) out